# Pesticide for plants?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, indoors, diseases, pesticide

For some reason, most of the plants at my house have some sort of bug, from mealy bugs to whiteflies to other crap. I've been spraying with soapy water but it's not working.

What pesticide can I buy to get rid of these bugs for a considerable amount of time? I've read that I can treat the leaves with *something* (ie. qtip with alcohol, neem oil, etc), but I work 7 days a week and that's impossible considering all the leaves of all the plants I would need to treat.

What spray would you recommend? I can buy or it can be home-made, but it has to be something that has a lasting effect.

Here are some pictures of some of the plants. I bought the plant in the last picture about two weeks ago, and it's already showing symptoms.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]